# Prolog sequence of symbols

Tags: prolog

i have such problem, how for arbitrarily entered  sequence of symbols to determine whether it contains all the symbols of the word in the same sequence as in the word. For example: a sequence of "development" contains symbols word "dont". I have no idea how to do this in Prolog

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just 'visit' both lists, until the second one ends, then the task has succeeded.

The recursive visit will check both heads:
  if match -> discard both else discard the left list' one

The match in Prolog can be done by means of equality, i.e.:

```
recursive([H|T1], [H|T2]) :- !, ...
```

since the cut remove alternatives, we are left to discard the mismatch

```
recursive([_|T], L) :- recursive(T, L).
```

Comment: Is the cut in the first predicate a good idea? Would it cause a failure to match `development` with `elope`?

Comment: @mbratch: I think you're correct... I was trying to give help without solving the homework, and (silly me !) preferred to avoid the ... -> ... ; ... construct.

Comment: I figured it was just an oversight and I knew what you meant. :)